# When is my multiple AFJSONRequestOperations finished?

Tags: iphone, ios, afnetworking, nsoperationqueue, afjsonrequestoperation

I am starting multiple AFJSONRequestOperation in a for loop like this:

```
for(NSString *obj in collection)

operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

         //NSLog(@"success");      

        }
        failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

How can I determine that all of my operations has finished?

I guess the operations are added a to the `operationQueue`in AFHTTPClient but I am not sure. Eitherway I dont know how to access the instance of the AFHTTPClient being used.

Answer (score 0):

Outside the loop, define a counter (int) which is initially set to the number of elements of collection. In *each* completion block (that explicitly means, in success AND failure handler!) decrement the counter by one. If it reaches zero, all requests have been finished.

Caution: I'm not completely sure, but as far as I know, `AFJSONRequestOperation` won't invoke the handler blocks when it will be *cancelled*. Please consult the docs. (Personally, I think this is a design issue - but alas ... )

There are more elegant solutions to this problem. However, this would require a more specialized set of classes and tools which help to implement common asynchronous design patterns, like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `AFJSONRequestOperation` objects in a `NSMutableArray` (I'm using `operations` in this case) instead of starting each one, then use the method :

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithURL:baseURL];
[client enqueueBatchOfHTTPRequestOperations:operations progressBlock:nil completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    // called when all operations have finished.
}];
```